# Find throw paths must precede expression in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, grep

I am trying to alias find and grep to a line as show below

```
alias f='find . -name $1 -type f -exec grep -i $2 '{}' \;'
```

I intend to run it as

```
f *.php function
```

but when I add this to .bash_profile and run it I am hit with

```
[a@a ~]$ f ss s
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aliases don't accept positional parameters. You'll need to use a function.

```
f () { find . -name "$1" -type f -exec grep -i "$2" '{}' \; ; }
```

You'll also need to quote some of your arguments.

```
f '*.php' function
```

This defers the expansion of the glob so that `find` performs it rather than the shell.

Comment: No luck there I added   `function f() { find . -name "$1" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i "$2"; }` to the .bash_profile and source it. Hits the same error `[a@a ~]$ f "*.php" function
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
`

Comment: @QuintinPar: The function definition and execution in your comment works for me without error. Double check to make sure what you're actually trying matches what you posted. Also, try `declare -f f` to display the function definition for verification. Also, it's not necessary to use the function keyword when you define a function using () (or vice versa). Bash is one of the few shells that accepts them together.

Comment: @quinton: you need to invoke f with the first argument in single quotes.  Using double quotes is very different.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Only if there's a variable or parameter expansion. There's no difference between double and single quotes for globbing. The special parameters `$*` and `$?` which have superficial similarity to globbing will be expanded inside double quotes unless the dollar sign is escaped (in the case that you're looking for a file with a literal dollar sign in that position in its name) or the specification is enclosed in single quotes. In the case of either single or double quotes, if you're looking for a filename which includes a literal asterisk, you'll need to escape it.

Comment: All of the preceding also applies to the square bracket character list or range globbing feature.

Comment: In my case I was missing the semicolon after the escaped one.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Dennis Williamson's solution:

```
f() { find . -name "$1" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i "$2"; }
```

Using `xargs` rather than `-exec` saves you from spawning a new process for each grep... if you have a lot of files, the overhead can make a difference.

Comment: You can get the same effect by using `+` instead of `\;` for versions of find that support it.